# Make TableView with nested collection

Tags: java, javafx

I have Employee class:

```
public class Employee {

    private long id;
    private String name;
    private List<String> days;

   //getters, setters and etc.
}
```

I know how to display id, name fields in TableView. But how to create a table in which the elements of the collection of an element of the table will also be in cells?

Comment: you might need to provide more details. are you reading the `Employee`s from a database, or from a simple `Collection`? etc...

Comment: @HakanDilek , from collection.

Comment: What do you want this to look like? You should potentially don’t know the number of days for each employee, and that number could vary from one employee to the next...

Comment: I don't think `TableView` is capable of doing what you want. _Maybe_ `TreeTableView` could be worked to fit your needs, but that might involve adapting the model. Otherwise, if the number of days is relatively small (e.g. max 7, depending on what you mean by "days") then you could just list each day vertically in one cell (e.g. with a `VBox`).

Comment: Check out JFoenix (https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix) library. On the GitHub page, scroll all the way down and click on "Grouping". If that's something that might work for you, you can use the `id` and / or `name` for the group and then when the group is opened, you show the list of `days`. Bad news is that's it's using `TreeTableView`, but at least there's a demo you can check out.